# Undefined Index errror with $code = $_REQUEST["code"]; for Facebook auth

Tags: facebook, indexing, undefined

Every time I go to the canvas page of my facebook app it briefly shows an error saying undefined index on the line with $code = $_REQUEST["code"]; at line 9. After this code shows it looks like it does a quick redirect and everything works fine. Does anyone know how to solve this? Here's my code at the top of the canvas:

```
<?php 

$app_id = "244958008880978";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$my_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/guessyguesser/";
session_register();
session_start();

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
$_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
$dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}



{
 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

 $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
 $params = null;
 parse_str($response, $params);

 $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
   . $params['access_token'];

 $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
}

?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add an @ to the beginning of line 9, or move line 9 below the `if` block and change line 11 to

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST["code"])) {
```

Oh, and also add an `exit` statement right after that `echo`.

Comment: ... OR instead of `$code = $_REQUEST["code"];`, the OP could use `$code = isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? $_REQUEST['code'] : NULL;`.